# Create folder while publishing with MSBuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I am Trying to create a Temp folder while doing the publish of my Web Application Project with file system location in Visual Studio 2015.I have tried adding the code below in .csfile but its not Creating folder in the target location of the Publish Directory.If given Static location to create folder its working fine.How can get Publish Directory dynamically?

```
<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(PublishDirectory)$(OutputDirectoryTemp)" />
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>   
    <OutputDirectoryTemp>\Temp\</OutputDirectoryTemp> 
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Create folder while publishing with MSBuild

You need to declare attributes `PublishDirectory` by creating an element with the attribute name as a child of the `PropertyGroup` element, because there is no such MSBuild Macros for this, you can check the [Common Macros for Build Commands and Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx).

As test, I set `PublishDirectory` to the path `D:\Publish`:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishDirectory>D:\Publish</PublishDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then I add a output command line `<Message Test="xxx" />` in the target to output the content of `$(PublishDirectory)$(OutputDirectoryTemp)`:

```
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(PublishDirectory)$(OutputDirectoryTemp)" />

    <Message Text="$(PublishDirectory)$(OutputDirectoryTemp)">
    </Message>
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputDirectoryTemp>\Temp\</OutputDirectoryTemp>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishDirectory>D:\Publish</PublishDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In the output window, you will see following log:

[image]

And the folder `Temp` would be created:

[image]

If you have already defined the variable of `PublishDirectory`, you can try to use the output command line `<Message Test="xxx" />` check if the path is correct.

**Update:**

> I will like to get the target location of the Publish Directory dynamically not static or hard coded

Since you want to get the target location of the Publish Directory **dynamically**, as we know, the location of the Publish Directory was stored in the `.pubxml` file, in the node `<publishUrl>D:\Publish\Test</publishUrl>`, to get this value dynamically, we could use `$(publishUrl)` to get this value in the target, However, **the publishing process is after the build**, we could not get this value in the build process, so we need to change the order of this target from `AfterTargets="Build"` to `AfterTargets="PipelineTransformPhase"`. The target should be:

```
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles" AfterTargets="PipelineTransformPhase">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(publishUrl)$(OutputDirectoryTemp)" />
    <Message Text="$(publishUrl)$(OutputDirectoryTemp)" />
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputDirectoryTemp>\Temp\</OutputDirectoryTemp>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In this case, when you publish your project to the system location, the publish directory will be stored in the `publishUrl`, we could get it in that target.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for response..I will like to get the target location of the Publish Directory dynamically not static or hard coded as you given(<PublishDirectory>D:\Publish</PublishDirectory>).

Comment: @user2642517, if you want to get the target location of the Publish Directory dynamically, you should get the location of the Publish Directory from the `publishUrl` and change the target order to `AfterTargets="PipelineTransformPhase"`. Check my updated answer for  details. Hope helps :).

Answer (score 1):

A little irrelevant at this point in time, but I think it may help someone like me. Whenever I searched how to dynamically add the folders and files **within the same project** in my publish profile in Azure DevOps, I landed on this question. So, I decided to put my answer here if it can help someone.

MSBuild expects you to make sure that you include certain files into the project file if you want Azure to deploy them during a git deployment. It is very frustrating, especially when you're using an external tool to copy files into a certain folder.

**Wouldn’t it be nice if Visual Studio and (therefore) MSBuild just recursively included and deployed a folder of files within the same project without you having to define it in the publish profile?**

You have to hand-edit the .csproj/.vbproj file (using Notepad++), but all you need to do is use a wildcard in the Include statement:

**MyProject.Web.vbproj**

```
<!-- double wildcards include all files and folders -->
<Content Include="folder\**" />

<!-- You can also filter certain type of files (e.g. .js files) -->
<Content Include="folder\*.min.js" />
```

It helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying your PropertyGroup before your target, to ensure it has been created.

Also check the value of PublishDirectory to make sure it is a valid path - I suspect it may come with a "\" on the end of it, so you're ending up with two slashes